# I cant seem to get regular css to work in my next js 13 project. im a noob pls

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, app-router

I cant seem to get the default css to work in my next 13 project. I have a page.modules.css file and i'm using classname = styles.style

page.tsx

```
import styles from'./page.module.css'
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.testStyle}>
      send help
    </div>
  )
}
```

page.module.css

```
.testStyle {
    border-width: 2;
    border-color: #990099;
}
```

Comment: Try `className={'testStyle'}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your css class to be like this:

```css
.testStyle {
  border: solid #990099 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

semicolon missing after )

```
import styles from './page.module.css';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.testStyle}>
      send help
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: add a semi-colon doesn't make the css work out of the blue.